# in python 'mailto:info@domain.com'.lstrip("mailto:") it is retuning "nfo@domain.com"

Tags: python

I'm looking to extract the core email address from a string that includes a 'mailto:' prefix. However, when I apply the strip function with the argument 'mailto:', it unexpectedly removes the 'i' character as well if email startswith character i. This behavior seems to be specific to the 'i' in 'mailto:'.
seems like a but in python I have tested on online python interpreter, but I got the same output.

For instance, when I use the code string.lstrip("mailto:"), it returns 'nfo@domain.com' instead of the expected 'info@domain.com'.

Comment: Use `removeprefix` if you are on python 3.9+

Comment: `lstrip` removes all **combination** of characters

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: 'mailto:info@domain.com'.lstrip("mailto:")
@ Abdul Niyas P M already explained and resolved that, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lstrip()` function removes all characters that are in the string "mailto:", meaning all occurrences of `"m, a, i, l, t, o, :"`. The reason that only the `"i"` is missing in your email address is that it contains none of the other characters that you are stripping.

If you know that the prefix is always exactly `"mailto:"` you can strip it like this:

```py
input_string = "mailto:info@domain.com"
email = input_string[len("mailto:"):]
print(email)
```